# shell script get ssh remote error

Tags: shell, ssh

I'm trying to make a remote mysqldump and afterwards download it with rsync which is all working good, but I also want to log the remote errors I get which I now only see in the terminal output.
I mean errors like this `mysqldump: Got error: 1044: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'information_schema' when using LOCK TABLES?`

This is the important part of my code:

```
MYSQL_CMD="mysqldump -u ${MYSQL_USER} -p${MYSQL_PASS} $db -r /root/mysql_${db}.sql"
$SSH -p ${SSH_PORT} ${SSH_USER}@${SSH_HOST} "${MYSQL_CMD}" >> "${LOGFILE}"
```

In my research I only found solutions for getting the exit code and return values.

I hope someone can give me a hint, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These error messages are being written to **stderr**. You can redirect this to a file using `2>` or `2>>` just like you do for stdout with `>` and `>>`. Eg:

```
ssh ... 2>/tmp/logerrors
```

Note there is no space between 2 and >.  You can merge stderr into the same file as stdout by replacing your `>> "${LOGFILE}"` with

```
ssh ... &>> "${LOGFILE}"
```

Again, no space in `&>`, which can also be written `>&`.

Comment: thanks for your very detailed description this was the missing hint for my problem